# How to run the this Time Counter in a Separate Thread or backgroundworker in C#?

Tags: c#

```
    private void time_counter_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        secs += 1;
        if (secs == 60)
        {
            secs = 0;
            mins += 1;
            if (mins == 60)
            {
                mins = 0;
                hrs += 1;
            }
        }
        time_counter_lbl.Text = getCurrentTimeString();
    }

    private void startTheCounter()
    {
        secs = mins = hrs = 0;

        time_counter.Start();
        time_lbl.Visible = true;
        time_counter_lbl.Visible = true;
    }

    private void stopTheCounter()
    {
        time_counter.Stop();
    }

    private string getCurrentTimeString()
    {
        string sec, min, hr;
        sec = min = hr = "";
        if (secs < 10)
            sec = "0" + secs.ToString();
        else
            sec = secs.ToString();
        if (mins < 10)
            min = "0" + mins.ToString();
        else
            min = mins.ToString();
        if (hrs < 10)
            hr = "0" + hrs.ToString();
        else
            hr = hrs.ToString();

        return hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
    }
```

In my application, db calls are there. In the same time i want to display the elasped time. But time label is not getting updated. Please help me, how to fix this in separate thread to solve this.

Comment: It's your DB work that you want to do in a seperate thread. So you can keep the UI thread free to update labels. The timer tick event should barely take up anything at all, assuming you have the interval set to 1 second.

Comment: Why don't you use the `StopWatch` class if it's just about timing the elapsed time. [Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch) is some simple example how to use it.

Comment: @musefan : Already db work in backgroundworker only and interval as you mentioned 1 second.

Answer (score 2):

The Timer should be able to update your label, put all the label updating code inside the time_counter_Tick()

If you want to know how to use a BackgroundWorker take reference to a question I posted a couple of years ago.

[Easy Threading in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466161/easy-threading-in-wpf)

The trick is that your UI logic has to execute on the UI thread. There are methods provided that make this easier than it might otherwise be, but using them can be tricky. Here's how I've done it in the past:

First, you have to declare a delegate that you can feed to the Dispatcher.Invoke method:

```
private delegate void UIDelegate();
```

Then you can get your background worker setup and call it's RunWorkerAsync method:

```
BackgroundWorker loadWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
loadWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(loadWorker_DoWork);
loadWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(loadWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
loadWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Then, to update UI elements, you have to invoke their dispatcher:

```
private void changeStatusLabel(string status)
{
    progressLabel.Dispatcher.Invoke(new UIDelegate(delegate
    {
        progressLabel.Content = status;
    }));
}
```

These are cut from larger methods and they can likely be optimized a bit. Still, that'll give you a place to start from.